# Does publishing to only test accounts cause "Could not fetch data from the Chrome Web Store" error

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to implement Inline Installation of a Chrome Extension (https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/inline_installation), but when I call chrome.webstore.install() I get back an error stating "Could not fetch data from the Chrome Web Store".

The extension is currently only published to a group of testers in a Google Group, of which I am a member (owner, actually), and I am able to install the extension just fine from the store itself.  But I'm wondering if this error is due to its being in this testing mode.  There doesn't seem to be any information in the Google Code docs, or anywhere on the web that I can find for this error.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has just been fixed yesterday: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=138155

The fix is already working on the Canary channel build. I don't know how long it takes to reach the other channels.